# Cannot connect to SQL Server using SSMS, but application can access it

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, port

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I have a connection string that connects to remote SQL Server `TestServer1`.

I ran the web application and I see the data in the application from the remote SQL Server with out any issues.

But when I try to connect to the remote SQL Server using SSMS, I get time out error.

I ran below commands in the command prompt

```
ping TestServer1 - success
telnet TestServer1 1433 - failed
```

I know we need to open port 1433 to connect from SSMS. But how the database is accessed from the web application?

Comment: Did you go to  Tools > Options-> Designers to increase the time out and see if this works?

Comment: Try it by IP address

Comment: We would need to see the connection string and exactly what you are entering to connect with SSMS.

Comment: Also, are you trying to connect from the same box that the ASP.net is running on?

Comment: Application is running in local computer, SQL Server running in different box. As the port 1433 is not open I cannot connect from local computer. I want to know how the application is connecting to sql server. Will it use some other port?

Comment: If port 1434 is open and the SQL Server Browser is listening, it can redirect the application to a different port, if SQL Server happens to be on that. If `TestServer1` is not the exact server name connected to, DNS resolution may mean you're actually going to a different server. Last but not least, you can [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/create-or-delete-a-server-alias-for-use-by-a-client) any server name to anything else for purposes of connecting with SQL.

Comment: That said, all of these explanations, while possible, are less likely than you just having the wrong idea about what the app is actually connecting to. Are you sure you're not missing an instance name, for example? (`TestServer1\instance`). Also, that you see a name in a .config somewhere doesn't necessarily make it so. Set a breakpoint to be sure.